# move sphere type object in unity using scripy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to move object `"sphere"` on each framrate forword. however,  `rb.AddForce(0, 0, 1500 * Time.deltaTime);` dont seem to be working. how can i move a "sphere" isealy?

full code:

```
   public Rigidbody rb;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, 1500 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

as far as i now, `rb.AddForce` is only vail for `cubes`, if it is not vail for `sphere` as well,  what is the way to move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)?

```
void FixedUpdate () {     
    rb.MovePosition(rb.transform.position + rb.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
}
```